# MYSQL concat match in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Courses
[image]

Users

[image]

**I want to show courses where courses author = name + first name from user table**

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `courses` as c WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * from `users` as u WHERE u.id_user = '63' AND c.author = CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.surname)
```

I get error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Thanks.

Comment: How about adding the ending parenthesis?

Comment: But your model is not correct. In the courses table (normaly a table is singular like "course") you need to store author id (not lastename+firstname ) linked to the id_user of user table.

Why ? For indexing, increase searching speed, ... And make a view with INNER JOIN to get results with a SELECT.

Comment: @Meloman I know I didn't create those table. there should be a connecting id but the person who made it doesn't want to change table. Anyways I found the solution below

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen lol that worked too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT c.* FROM `courses` as c 
JOIN `users` as u 
ON c.author = CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.surname)
WHERE u.id_user = '63'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `courses` u
join `users` u on c.author = CONCAT(u.name, ' ', u.surname)
WHERE u.id_user = '63'
```

U need to join here.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
select * from courses where author in (select concat(name,' ',surname)  
from Users);
```